# Multimodule Go Importing From Wrong Path

Tags: go, go-modules

I have the following structure:

```
gateway-service
  config
    config.go
  go.mod
  go.sum
  service.go
logger
  logger.go
  go.mod
  go.sum
```

In `config.go` I import the following:

```
import (
    "errors"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)
```

Now, the top level packages are fine and import correctly. However, the viper package does not. The error message is:

```
could not import github.com/spf13/viper (cannot find package "github.com/spf13/viper" in any of 
    /Users/me/.go/src/github.com/spf13/viper (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/spf13/viper (from $GOPATH))compiler
```

The same issue happens in the `logger.go` file:

```
package logger

import (
    "context"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)
```

The error is:

```
could not import go.uber.org/zap (cannot find package "go.uber.org/zap" in any of 
    /Users/me/.go/src/go.uber.org/zap (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/go/src/go.uber.org/zap (from $GOPATH))compiler
```

I've tried installing with:

```
go get github.com/spf13/viper
go get go.uber.org/zap
go mod tidy
```

gateway-service/go.mod

```
module github.com/puul/gateway-service

go 1.15

require github.com/spf13/viper v1.3.2
```

logger/go.mod

```
module github.com/puul/logger

go 1.15

require (
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.6.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/zap v1.16.0
)
```

Go env:

```
▶ echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/go

▶ echo $GOROOT
/Users/me/.go
```

On a related note, I'd love to know if there was a simpler way to achieve a structure like this:

```
pkg
  logger
    logger.go
services
  gateway
```

**Edit**

My guess is that I have a conflict somehow between modules and GOPATH. Frankly, it's not clear from documentation how the two interact. Autoimports appear to be broken in VSCode as a result. It should be pulling from the path given in the import but it is not. What determines that import path is the core issue.

Comment: have you try 'go run/build' ?
I suspect VSCode might be usign a different "go" binary or GOPATH

Comment: Go build within logger works but within gateway-service fails `cannot find module providing package github.com/puul/logger` @aclowkay

Comment: For these kinds of issues it would be helpful to post the output of `go version` and `go env`, run in the same directory in which you observed the error.

(Also note that the `go` command infers the current module from its working directory, so which directory you run commands in _really_ matters.)

Answer (score 1):

The `(from $GOPATH)` strings in the error message indicates that the `go` command invocation that produced that error was running in `GOPATH` mode, not module mode — which probably means that your current working directory was not within either of the two modules.

In general we recommend using a single module for your code unless you have a strong need to release different sets of packages at different times.

If you are using VSCode to edit code across multiple modules, you may need to configure your workspace to tell it which is the main module; see the [`build.experimentalWorkspaceModule`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#buildexperimentalworkspacemodule) setting.

You may also need (or want) to plumb the `logger` module into the `gateway-service` module using a [`replace` directive](https://golang.org/doc/modules/gomod-ref#replace).